# Android gmail can't scale background image correctly

Tags: android, gmail, html-email, apple-mail

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <td>
    <table align="center" background="{{imgUrl}}" height="461" width="597">
      <tr>
        <td width="597" height="461">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

See code above.  On android, the image is not scaled correctly. See image attached.[image]  Is there anyone who know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by gmail auto-sizing and could be fixed by applying min-width -- `style="min-width:597px;"`

Ideas from - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7733/android-gmail-image-resizing-issues/

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/ - FYI - background images do not work at all in Outlook or some versions of Android.

Comment: @gwallyThanks for the heads-up!  For now we don't have plan to deal with outlook support~

Comment: @HaoyuChen try [Bulletproof Backgrounds](http://backgrounds.cm) works on a LOT of clients.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the table a width & height same as the td inside it. You should be able to use media queries to control the table height.

Try this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
     @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
     .bannerTable{width:100% !important;height:auto !important;}
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <td>
    <table align="center" background="{{imgUrl}}" width="597" style="width:100%; max-width:597px; height:461px;display:block;" class="bannerTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Content goes here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you